# Table data change to one sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I trying to find way to change table data to one sentence
For example
If i have a table

```
  Data
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
```

and i want it to change as '1 2 3 4 5'

:D

ok to make it clear.

I declare a vairable @k1 nvarchar(200)
select @k1 = keyword from keyword where concept_id = (select Concept_ID from concept where @concept_name = Concept_name)

so this variable returns a table as shown above example
like 
      keyword
          1
          2
          3
          .
          .

and if i used this variable into freetext

```
 select id as Post_ID, post as Txt from Post 
 where freetext (post, @k1)
 end
```

It shows the result but the result is only @ki is recognised as last word of the table
So i want to @k1 can be including all the data from the table so the freetext function can find any words in @k1

:C;; hard to exaplain..

Comment: search for pivot examples

Answer (score 1):

you can use stuff function to make it

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ' '+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),DATA) FROM SAMPLE 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,(''))
```

Sample below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4c05/3

Answer (score 0):

Use that code:

```
declare @result nvarchar(max) = ''

select @result = @result + [data] + ' ' from tble1

print rtrim(@result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the resultset in a table like you have shown and use `COALESCE` [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) .

```
DECLARE @List varchar(max)

SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ' ', '') + Data 
FROM <yourTable>
```